# Why does a file appear in Flask when I hadn't uploaded anything in the form?

Tags: python, flask

What exactly does this mean? I skipped the upload file part in my program.

[image]

`file = request.files.get(entries.img, 'no_img')`

I have never seen this before, what does it mean? Since I uploaded nothing, file should be equal to 'no_img'.

Comment: You're definitely missing [a _whole_ bunch of details here](/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit] your post to include all those details, ideally as a description of steps that reproduce the problem with enough [mcve] code that lets people see which code is involved in each step.